# vmware esxi RAM configurations

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

We want to increase total RAM size in 3 of our vmware esxi nodes.

My question is that as long as the total size of the RAM on each node is the same, does not matter what size of each individual chip i use in 3 nodes? (the type and frequency of the ram will be the same. )

something Like this:

```
24 x 16G = 384G in node1
12 x 32G = 384G in node2
12 x 32G = 384G in node3
```

Is this doable or everything must be identical? is there anything else we need to concern?

Comment: The amount of RAM in each node doesn't have to be the same.

Comment: well, if you have HA, DRS and admission control configured, it need to be the same for failovers.

Comment: `well, if you have HA, DRS and admission control configured, it need to be the same for failovers.` - That isn't technically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not matter.

Is there a reason you you think the composition of total RAM in a node would make a difference?

Comment: I thought it should not be an issue, but just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The memory configuration does not matter. The only hardware aspect that matters is the CPU generation and chipset matching, to get the best vmotion support. It is best to have the systems match at that level.